# python ahrs complementary filter yields error for shape

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to use ahrs' [Complementary filter](https://ahrs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filters/complementary.html), but can't get it working.
The shape of the data:

```
for ele in zip(gl, al): 
  comp.append(ahrs.filters.complementary.Complementary(ele[0],ele[1],None,200))
```

where `ele[0]` (gyroscope data) looks like `[ 0.75    0.6875 -0.625 ]` and `ele[1]` (accelerometer data) looks like `[ 0.03125    -0.08935547  1.01123047]`

The datatype of both arrays is `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` as demanded by the Complementary function.

The current error comes from the framework itself where it states

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/luke/test_imu.py", line 111, in <module>
    comp.append(ahrs.filters.complementary.Complementary(ele[0],ele[1],None,200))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ahrs/filters/complementary.py", line 158, in __init__
    self.Q = self._compute_all()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ahrs/filters/complementary.py", line 184, in _compute_all
    Q[0] = self.am_estimation(self.acc[0], self.mag[0]) if self.q0 is None else self.q0.copy()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ahrs/filters/complementary.py", line 283, in am_estimation
    if acc.shape[-1] != 3:
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

the problem therefore is, that the line `Q[0] = self.am_estimation(self.acc[0], self.mag[0]) if self.q0 is None else self.q0.copy()` takes the first element off the 3-size ndarray with `self.acc[0]`. Of course the value is then the wrong shape.

So is there a error in the framework or in my data structure? How do i fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

The acc and gyr arrays are n * 3 arrays.  you may by the looks of things only have 1x3 arrays.